# Most powerful test when the level of the test is 0

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics

Suppose we have continuous-time distributions with densities $f_0(x)$ and $f_1(x)$ under the null and alternative hypotheses, respectively. Show that if the level of the test is $\alpha=0$ then $\phi(x)=\{f_0(x)=0\}$ is the most powerful test.

**My attempt**:

Suppose there exists a test $\phi^*(x)$ with the same level $\alpha=0$. We want to prove that $\mathbb E_1[\phi(x)-\phi^*(x)]\geq 0$. We have:
\begin{align}
E_1[\phi(x)-\phi^*(x)]&=\int(\phi(x)-\phi^*(x))f_1(x)dx\\
&=\int_{\phi(x)=1}\mathbb I_{\phi(x)-\phi^*(x)=1}f_1(x)dx-\int_{\phi(x)=0}\mathbb I_{\phi(x)-\phi^*(x)=-1}f_1(x)dx\\
&=A-B
\end{align}
Consider the integral $A$:

\begin{align}
A\geq \int_{\phi(x)=1}\mathbb I_{\phi(x)-\phi^*(x)=1}f_0(x)dx
\end{align}
as when $\phi(x)=1$, $f_0(x)=0$. Now if we can show that $B\leq \int_{\phi(x)=0}\mathbb I_{\phi(x)-\phi^*(x)=-1}f_0(x)dx$, then basically the proof is done. However, I cannot argue the inequality for $B$.

**My Question:**
How to prove the inequality for $B$ or are there any other ways to approach this problem? Thank you!

Comment: How can a test have *any* power when the standard for rejection is a p-value of exactly zero?